# Is Aristotle’s virtue theory somewhat similar to the Doctrine of the mean?

Tags: aristotle, virtue-ethics, confucius

Doctrine of the mean: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_of_the_Mean

The two theories strike me as surprisingly similar in how they emphasize “the right amount”: not lacking and also not in excess.

Comment: Yes, See [Aristotle: Ethics](https://iep.utm.edu/aris-eth/): "In the *Nichomachean Ethics*, Aristotle repeatedly states that virtue is a mean. The mean is a state of clarification and apprehension in the midst of pleasures and pains that allows one to judge what seems most truly pleasant or painful. This active state of the soul is the condition in which all the powers of the soul are at work in concert. Achieving good character is a process of clearing away the obstacles that stand in the way of the full efficacy of the soul."

Comment: Aristotle has what is literally called "doctrine of the mean" about virtues, see [Losin, Aristotle's Doctrine of the Mean](http://www.plosin.com/work/AristotleMean.html). For comparison see Fang Xia's dissertation [A Comparative Study of Two Doctrines of the Mean between Aristotle and Confucius](https://era.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1842/3621/Fang%20Xia%20MSc%202009.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y) and Jiyuan Yu's book [The Ethics of Confucius and Aristotle: Mirrors of Virtue](https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/the-ethics-of-confucius-and-aristotle-mirrors-of-virtue/).

Comment: @Conifold thank you!